# Segmentation Fault em array de Structs C

Tags: c, struct

Estou tentando fazer um array de structs dinâmico em C, porém não estou entendendo porque está me retornando segmentation fault.

O código é basicamente este:

Só estou criando um vetor de 10 arrays e depois tentando inicializar cada struct individualmente, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_NODES 10000
#define INF 999999999

typedef struct Node{  
        int value;  
        int listaAdj[MAX_NODES];  
        int pesoArestas[MAX_NODES];  
        int visited;  
}Node;

//variaveis globais
Node *grafo;
int numVertices = 10;


int main(){

    int i,j;
    grafo =  (Node*) malloc((numVertices) * sizeof(struct Node*)); 


    for ( i = 0; i < numVertices; i++ ){
            if ( i == 0 ){
                    grafo[i].value = 0;            
            }else{
                    grafo[i].value = INF;          
            }

            for ( j = 0; j < MAX_NODES; j++ ){
                    grafo[i].listaAdj[j] = -1;
                    grafo[i].pesoArestas[j] = -1;          
            }
    grafo[i].visited = 0;
    }


    for ( i = 0; i < numVertices; i++ ){
            printf(" %d \n", grafo[i].value);
    }

    free(grafo);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Desculpa gente, eu não consigo por código na minha pergunta, como faço isso?

Comment: Colando ele e usando o marcador apropriado no editor. É o que aparece `{ }`

Comment: ae, agora fico show, conseguem detectar o problema?

Comment: Ps: esqueci de coloca, MAX_NODES esta definido como 10.000

Comment: @avoid porque você tirou uma parte relevante do código? Deste jeito ficou difícil resolver alguma coisa.

Comment: meu código inteiro está ai, só falta as importações de stdlib e stdio

Comment: Não estava, você tinha tirado e eu coloquei de volta.

Comment: @avoid, Sempre que for uma dúvida do tipo *"por que meu código não funciona?"*, lembre-se de incluir um código **completo** e **compilável** na pergunta. Sem isso outros não tem nem como testar.

Comment: Veja mais em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grafo = (Node*)malloc((numVertices) * sizeof(struct Node*));
```

Lendo com bastante cuidado esse código: Calcule o tamanho de **um pointeiro para** a struct e aloca um certo número desses **ponteiros**. Acredito que você queira alocar structs e não ponteiros para structs. Remova o último asterísco da linha, assim:

```
grafo = (Node*)malloc((numVertices) * sizeof(struct Node));
```

E claro, os parênteses no `numVertices` e a conversão de tipo no final é redundante. Pode escrever apenas:

```
grafo = malloc(numVertices * sizeof(struct Node));
```

Comment: Funcionou cara, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

O tamanho de cada elemento está mal.

```
//grafo =  (Node*) malloc((numVertices) * sizeof(struct Node*));
grafo = malloc(numVertices * sizeof *grafo);
```